# How to color a steep plane based on its height using vertex shader?

Tags: three.js, graphics, glsl, shader, webgl

I made a plane in THREEjs using Mesh, PlaneGeometry and ShaderMaterial. It's a very simple/basic form. I applied a simple phormula to make the plain more steep. Now I'm trying to make the terrain to be colored based on its height using vertex shaders. For example, the top could be color 1, the middle color 2 and so on...

Here's what I tried:

Vertex shader:

```
varying vec3 vColor;

void main(void) {
    float uAmp = 20.0;

    float z = uAmp * sin(position.x*0.7) * cos(position.y*0.7);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.x, position.y, z, 1.0);

    if (gl_Position.z <= 2.0*uAmp/3.0) {
        vColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
    else if (gl_Position.z <= 2.0*uAmp*(2.0/3.0)) {
        vColor = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); //this goes to fragment shader
    }
    else {
        vColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //this goes to fragment shader
    }
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

        varying vec3 vColor;
        
        void main(void) {   
            gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
            }
```

This doesn't produce the expected result. Instead, the object is almost fully blue:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only care about the unprojected value of Z. Does it work if you change

```
if (z <= 2.0*uAmp/3.0) {
   vColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized that from this code, the effect is: if a curve is "tall" then it's color A, if it is medium then it is color B and the rest is color C which was not the effect I intended. I wanted the 1/3 of the curve were color A, 2/3 color B and the rest color C. Would you know why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 0):

If I would want to paint a tarrain by its height, I'd take the approach with a texture of colours:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.151.3/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import {OrbitControls} from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import {SimplexNoise} from "three/addons/math/SimplexNoise.js";

let simplex = new SimplexNoise();

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 5);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", event => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());

// terrain
let g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100).rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
let pos = g.attributes.position;
let uvs = g.attributes.uv;
let uv = new THREE.Vector2();
for(let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
  uv.fromBufferAttribute(uvs, i).multiplyScalar(2.5);
  let y = simplex.noise(uv.x, uv.y) * 1.5; // noise is in range -1..1
  pos.setY(i, y);
}
let m = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  wireframe: true,
  uniforms: {
    minHeight: {value: -1.5},
    maxHeight: {value: 1.5},
    heightTexture: {value: getTexture()}
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying float h;
    void main(){
      h = position.y;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform float minHeight;
    uniform float maxHeight;
    uniform sampler2D heightTexture;
    varying float h;
    void main(){
      
      float hRatio = clamp((h - minHeight) / (maxHeight - minHeight), 0., 1.);
      gl_FragColor = texture(heightTexture, vec2(hRatio, 0.5));
    } 
  `
});
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

renderer.setAnimationLoop( _ => {
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

// color texture
function getTexture(){
  let c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = 1024;
  c.height = 1;
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, 0);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "#ff0000");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "#00ff00");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "#0000ff");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  let texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(c);
  return texture;
}
</script>
```